# Number of bytes recv()'d larger than the amount of data stored in the buffer?

Tags: c, sockets

My code looks something like this:

```
char buffer[BUFSIZE];
while (1) {
    memset(buffer, 0, BUFSIZE);
    ssize_t received = recv(csock, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0);
    printf("Received %lu blen %lu\n", received, strlen(buffer));
    ...
}
```

Sometimes, the output of my printf statement is:

```
Received 1045 buffer GETFILE OK 233174

���� blen 25
```

How is this possible? If recv() store all the data it got in the buffer, shouldn't `strlen(buffer)` be the number of bytes received?

Comment: `recv()` does not write a `'\0'` (unless it read one). `strlen()` is the wrong tool because there is no guarantee the "buffer" is a string

Comment: Do you mean I should null-terminate the buffer by adding `buffer[received] = '\0'`, before I use any string functions on it?

Comment: If that's what you want, **yes**. Make sure to avoid buffer overflows.

Comment: @bard a better solution is to use the `received` value that `recv()` returns, and not rely on mutating the contents of the `buffer` at all. `char buffer[BUFSIZE]; ssize_t received; while ( (received = recv(csock, buffer, BUFSIZE, 0)) > 0 ) { printf("Received %lu\n%.*s\n", received, received, buffer); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlen` counts the number of bytes until one of the bytes is 0.

It does not tell you how many bytes are received. That's just not what it does.

Only `recv` knows how many bytes it received.